# When exactly type erasure occurs?

Tags: scala, mixins, type-erasure

The syntax of scala is very promising. I thought originally scala is more than just comfortable java and can introduce totally new programming paradigm, but many features allowed by syntax is incorrect in semantics. So I started a quest of finding scala limitations and hacks to eliminate them. Although I just writing a test project to accommodate to scala ways and patterns from other point of view.

The main obstacle is type erasure inherited from jvm implementation. I can write a small article named "Ten beautiful patterns that type erasure has ruined". It is spoken that type erasure taints generics but I've stumbled on type erasure in mixins. I consider it problem with the mixin realization in scala.

Preamble

```
trait T1
trait T2

trait B1 {
  def typeMe(x:T1){}
}
```

Broken Code with mixins

```
trait B2 extends B1 {
  def typeMe(x:T1 with T2) {}
}
```

Working Code with mixin declared as separate trait

```
trait T3 extends T1 with T2
trait B3 extends B1 {
  def typeMe(x:T3) {}
}
```

The error is:

```
error: name clash between defined and inherited member:
method typeMe:(x: T1 with T2)Unit and
method typeMe:(x: T1)Unit in trait B1
have same type after erasure: (x: $line12.$read#$iw#$iw#T1)Unit
    def typeMe(x:T1 with T2)
```

What is the best workaround available? Introducing new trait is verbosing (for large mixin chains especially) and leads to type incompatibilities. Adding mock implicit arguments is not the silver bullet as well because it increases overhead.

---

update:

I'm very sorry, I've asked the wrong question. I'm interested more in nature of the described error, not in its workarounds. Where does type erasure occurs? I see no generics in code that is considered to be type erasure source. What is the mechanics behind the compiler behaviour?

Comment: You may consider an alternative to overloaded methods; name them differently or use the typeclass pattern.

Comment: I hope you realise that in `B3` you're not overriding method `typeMe` from `B1`, but overloading it to take a sub-type. While this is legal, it's a bad idea, since the method called will depend on the type of the local variable. i.e. assuming a `B3` object `b3` and a `T3` object `t3`, `b3.typeMe(t3)` and `b3.typeMe(t3: T1)` will call different methods.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple problems with what you are trying to do.

Firstly, it doesn't matter when type erasure happens. This is because the concept of type erasure is that whether you erase the types before or after computation, the result should be the same. For JVM languages, some erasure happens at compile time, iinm.

Secondly, your "working" code doesn't actually work the way you think it does. This requires a little understanding about subtyping, covariance, and contravariance. (`Foo <: Bar` means "Foo is a subtype of Bar", or informally, that "Foo is more specific than Bar"). Functions are contravariant in their input, and covariant in their output, meaning that a function `A => B <: W => V` only if `W <: A` and `B <: V`.

Now consider your functions:

```
B1.typeMe(x:T1)
B3.typeMe(x:T3)
```

The input to `B3.typeMe` is `T3`, while the input type to `B1.typeMe` is `T1`. However, `T3 <: T1` (T3 is *more specific* than T1), therefore the type of `B3.typeMe` *cannot* be a subtype of the type of `B1.typeMe`. Instead, they are simply considered separate functions, with some eerie silent shadowing going on sometimes. In all honestly, this should probably emit an error or at least a warning. Thankfully, the other version does.

Comment: I had written not the actual question. The main question was where does type erasure occurs, what generics stands behind the error.